# HaProxy to keep the sourceIP of the connection

Tags: haproxy

HaProxy seems to delete the source IP info that I need to use to balance a socket.io service for one application. Could you please help me with how to configure Haproxy to keep that information?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

An option can be the usage of forwardfor: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-option%20forwardfor.